Number of Rectangles in Grid Including Diagonals

Find the number of rectangles in a rectangular $10 \times 6$ grid of points.

It is clear that for rectangles with horizontal/vertical edges, the number is $_{10}C_2\times_6C_2 = 675$. However, I am not sure how to proceed with finding all diagonal rectangles? I know that for any square of side length $k$ units contained in the grid, there are $k-1$ diagonal squares with points on the boundary of that square.
For example, see this square of side length k = 4 units:

There are k - 1 = 3 diagonal squares.
But how would I systematically proceed with finding diagonal rectangles?

Can you clarify which are the $k-1$ diagonal squares? EG for $k = 3$, I see 8 diagonal squares in a  $ 4 \times 4 $ grid (of side length 3).

I put a picture of the diagram

For any dimension of diagonal rectangle find the smallest axis-aligned rectangle that encloses it.  There will be the same number of diagonal rectangles as there were the size of axis-aligned rectangles enclosing it.  Below I have a figure of a $5 \times 5$ grid of points $(4 \times 4$ size) and a $1 \times 2$ diagonal rectangle.  The rectangle fits within a $3 \times 3$ size square, so there will be as many of the diagonal rectangles as $3 \times 3$ size squares fit in your grid.  Here there are $4$ positions for the square, so there will be $4$ diagonal $1 \times 2$ rectangles.
As the grid gets larger you need to decide if your diagonal rectangles are just the ones at a $45^\circ$ angle or if you accept ones based on a $3,4,5$ triangle.

